# Why do we represent planes this way?

Tags: linear-algebra

A plane is represented as a direction vector multiplied by the difference of points on the plane...Why?

Source: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ronmiech/Calculus_Problems/32A/chap11/section5/717d51/717_51.html

Right after "...The general equation of a plane is:"

Comment: The first part is not the direction vector. $\vec{n}$ represents the normal to the plane. In a lot of cases (like finding the shortest distance between a point and a plane) this representation of a plane is very useful.

Comment: Oh.. and this representation is right, because every vector from a point in the plane to another point in the plan (the difference) multiplicated (scalar) with the normal is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is a vector orthogonal to the plane and $P_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is a point of the plane, then any other point $P = (x, y, z)$ is in the plane if and only if $P_0P$ is orthogonal to $n$, that is if and only if $n \cdot P_0P = 0$.

Comment: What is $P_o P$ ?

Comment: It is the vector from $P_0$ to $P$, maybe I should have put an arrow over it... :) Note that its coordinates are $(x - x_0, y - y_0, z - z_0)$

Comment: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ronmiech/Calculus_Problems/32A/chap11/section5/717d51/717_51.html

Here he finds the normal vector by subtracting the two points. I don't understand what he is doing? Is that a normal vector?

Comment: No, $\vec{n}$ is the normal vector. The other vector $(x-x_{0},y-y_{0},z-z_{0})$ is a vector in the plane. Do you understand what a normal vector is?

Comment: Yes. But why is he multiplying the direction vector (denoted $P_0 P$ in your answer) with the 'difference' of the points?

He starts by taking the difference of the points and calling it $n$. $n = x_o - x, y_o - y, z_o - z$ this is confusing me greatly because $n$ is usually a normal vector and he is using this new $n$ vector as a normal vector.

Comment: Perhaps a picture helps. http://imgur.com/igtJeE4

Comment: @Paze The set of points that are equidistant from the points $A $ and $B$ is the plane orthogonal to $\vec{AB}$ which contains the midpoint of the segment $AB$. (If you don't understand why this is the case, try and solve the problem in $\mathbb R^2$ first.) So yes, we take $\vec{n} := \vec{AB}$; its coordinates are $(x_b - x_a, y_b - y_a, z_b - z_a)$. ($A = (1, 1, 0)$ and $B = (0, 0, 1)$ in the problem.)

Comment: Am I understand this correct now? The difference vector between P1 and P2 is obviously orthogonal due to the nature of the problem, http://i.imgur.com/X2sW4Wf.png

The other point is supposed to be P2 but I overwrote it accidentally.

Comment: @Paze That's correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try. Maybe it makes sense if you calculate the equation of the plane with the distance formula (in squared form). Let $(x,y,z)$ be a point of the plane. Then we wish to establish $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-0)^2=(x-0)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2$. Now work out the brackets, all quadratic terms cancel and you get the equation of your plane. Hope this alternative method helps...

Answer (score 1):

(1) As other responders previously said, a plane in the 3-dimensional space can be represented by a normal (i.e. perpendicular to the plane) vector $\overrightarrow{n}$ and an initial point $P_0$ (lying in the plane). To understand it geometrically, just think, for example of $\overrightarrow{n}$ as a vertical vector -- what is perpendicular to it? Everything horizontal, i.e. a horizontal plane, which would be specified once you pick a point it must contain.

(2) Then this geometrical fact is expressed algebraically using dot products. If $P_0(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is that given initial point in the plane, and $P(x,y,z)$ is an arbitrary point in the plane, then the vector $\overrightarrow{P_0P}$ lies in the plane; and at the same time $\overrightarrow{n}=\langle A,B,C\rangle$ is perpendicular to it; so they are perpendicular to each other. This fact is expressed as a dot product $\overrightarrow{n}\cdot\overrightarrow{P_0P}=0$, which expands into $A(x-x_0)+B(y-y_0)+C(z-z_0)=0$.

(3) Now, there's the confusion (very common among students) between directional and normal vectors. You must understand that these words are not properties of a vector per se, but rather some relative descriptors -- what this vector is in relation to something else. Let's say, you have a line perpendicular to a plane. Then the vector going in the direction of the line is directional for that line -- because it's in the direction of the line, and at the same time normal to the plane -- because it's perpendicular to it.

(4) And finally, the solution on that webpage that you linked made an unfortunate choice of words. I think they shouldn't have called that vector "directional", but instead should've just said "The vector between the two points ...". To understand the solution, you just observe that this vector is perpendicular to the desired plane, and thus it **can serve as normal** to construct its equation.